# What is the subscription validation event message schema in azure event grid?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, cloudevents

1. Created new azure event grid domain with cloud event schema using portal.
2. Created new web hook endpoint using azure function that can receive both subscription validation event as well as event notifications.
3. Created new azure event grid topic for the above domain (as part of following subscription) using portal.
4. Created new azure event grid subscription with cloud event schema with the above web hook endpoint.
5. When the subscription is Created, the endpoint was invoked by the grid infrastructure with subscription validaiton event to verify web hook endpoint.

To my surprise, the validation event structure (shown below) seemed to conform to native event grid schema and not cloud event schema:

```
[{
    "id": "6309ef83-117f-47aa-a07c-50f6e71a8ca5",
    "topic": "/subscriptions/13ad1203-e6d5-4076-bf2b-73465865f9f0/resourceGroups/xxxx-sandbox-rg/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/eg-xxx-test-cloud-domain/topics/eg-xxx-test-cloud-topic",
    "subject": "",
    "data": {
        "validationCode": "391889BB-FCC3-4269-A2BD-0918B5BAB0AE",
        "validationUrl": "https://rp-westus.eventgrid.azure.net/eventsubscriptions/xxxx-subscription-3/validate?id=391889BB-FCC3-4269-A2BD-0918B5BAB0AE&t=2019-01-30T15:45:37.0521594Z&apiVersion=2018-09-15-preview&[Hidden Credential]"
    },
    "eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
    "eventTime": "2019-01-30T15:45:37.0521594Z",
    "metadataVersion": "1",
    "dataVersion": "2"
}]
```

I expected following subscription validation event that conforms to cloud event schema (based on the 0.1 version of cloud event schema at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema#cloudevent-schema):

```
{
    "eventID" : "6309ef83-117f-47aa-a07c-50f6e71a8ca5",
    "source" : "/subscriptions/13ad1203-e6d5-4076-bf2b-73465865f9f0/resourceGroups/xxxx-sandbox-rg/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/eg-xxx-test-cloud-domain/topics/eg-xxx-test-cloud-topic",
    "data": {
        "validationCode": "391889BB-FCC3-4269-A2BD-0918B5BAB0AE",
        "validationUrl": "https://rp-westus.eventgrid.azure.net/eventsubscriptions/xxxx-subscription-3/validate?id=391889BB-FCC3-4269-A2BD-0918B5BAB0AE&t=2019-01-30T15:45:37.0521594Z&apiVersion=2018-09-15-preview&[Hidden Credential]"
    },
    "eventType" : "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
    "eventTime" : "2019-01-30T15:45:37.0521594Z",
    "cloudEventsVersion" : "0.1",
    "eventTypeVersion" : "2",
}
```

What am I missing thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the webhook subscriber is handling the following two groups of the events. The specific event type is stored in the http header 'aeg-event-type'.

1. **Internal** events of the Event Grid model such as the eventTypes *SubscriptionValidation* and *SubscriptionDeletion*. The schema for these event types are always the same as a default schema such as an  *EventGridSchema*. In other words, it's not depended on the *EventDeliverySchema*. IMO, having the default schema for internal events is making a strong event types specially when we have a CustomInputSchema.
2. **Interest source** events (topics) are events defined by input schema and presently the Event Grid model supports 3 types such as *EventGridSchema* (default), *CloudEventSchema* and *CustomInputSchema*. 
   The AEG supports the following schema input/output mappings:

   1. *EventGridSchema* to delivery schemas *EventGridSchema* and *CloudEventSchema*
   2. **CloudEventSchema** to delivery schema only **CloudSchemaSchema**
   3. *CustomInputSchema* to delivery schema *EventGridSchema* and *CloudEventSchema* and *CustomInputSchema*

   The event type in the header is: *aeg-event-type=Notification* and the schema is based on subscribed EventDeliverySchema (see the following mappings).

Based on the above, for your scenario you should have a separate strong type objects for Internal events (default schema is EventGridSchema) and for Notification events based on the subscribed EventDeliverySchema.

The following is an example of the http headers:

```
aeg-subscription-name=EVENTGRIDSCHEMA
aeg-delivery-count=0
aeg-data-version=
aeg-metadata-version=0
aeg-event-type=SubscriptionValidation
```

Note, there is only a subscription name to figure out which an EventDeliverySchema has been subscribed. It will be nice to have an additional aeg header for example: *aeg-subscription-labels* to pass some subscription metadata to the subscriber handler.

As a workaround, we can pass to the subscriber webhook handler some values via the url query parameters, for instance: *&eds=CustomInputSchema*

Comment: Is "Interest source" equally applicable for domains (in addition to topics)?

Comment: Yes, it is. In this event source is using a CustomInputSchema very useful. For testing purposes, have a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester, it is up to date included an Event Domains preview.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue / expected behavior in the Azure Event Grid implementation of Cloud Event V0.1 spec. At the time Cloud Events v0.1 spec was implemented in Azure Event Grid, there was no validation handshake / abuse protection model defined in the Cloud Events standard and hence Event Grid's existing validation handshake model/schema was used for Cloud Event subscribers as well.

Comment: You are talking about data portion. I am talking about metadata portion. The validation information is embedded in the data portion. This is completely unrelated to metadata. Why does not the metadata portion conform to what I configurd on the subscription (Cloud event schema)? With current configuration, I have to tell our consumers to respect native grid schema for validation event and cloud event schema for regular events.

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of supporting cloud event schema because consumer now needs to know 2 schema types. Granted that this is json, I can skillfully navigate over the json to get what I want. But I would like to provide class library to our clients based on the cloud event schema without ever referring to native grid schema or cloud event schema. Hope you understand my discomfort.